# HNQ links sometimes hard to see

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, hot-questions

The Hot Network Questions tab exists on many sites. It is (almost) always dark-ish text on a white background. Usually, links that I've clicked on before change color, which helps me keep track of what I've seen before.

The problem is that that's not the case on all sites. On some sites, the links are blue by default, and turn dark when clicked. On others there's barely any difference at all.

Please make the links have the same colors on all sites.

Some examples:
Visible just fine: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/
Hard to see: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/
Impossible: https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: didn't find the other question when searching, sorry